# How to get clickable elements to list in Selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I need list clickable elements on page? How to do this correctly?

Comment: What is "clickable" element? The same as "visible"?

Answer (score 0):

The [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions.htm) for **interactability** / **clickability** are:

- [ElementToBeClickable Method (By)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable.htm)

  ```
  public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> ElementToBeClickable(
      By locator
  )

  Parameters
        locator
            Type: OpenQA.Selenium.By
            The locator used to find the element.

  Return Value
      Type: Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement>
      The IWebElement once it is located and clickable (visible and enabled).
  ```
- [ElementToBeClickable Method (IWebElement)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable_1.htm)

  ```
  public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> ElementToBeClickable(
      IWebElement element
  )

  Parameters
      element
            Type: OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement
            The element.

  Return Value
      Type: Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement>
      The IWebElement once it is clickable (visible and enabled).
  ```

So both the *ExpectedConditions* for *clickability* / *interactability* returns a *IWebElement*. Hence you can't use them directly.

---

### Solution

A possible solution to create a *List* of clickable elements would be to use either of the following *ExpectedConditions*:

- [VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy Method (By)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy.htm)

  ```
  public static Func<IWebDriver, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>> VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
      By locator
  )

  Parameters
        locator
            Type: OpenQA.Selenium.By
            The locator used to find the elements.

  Return Value
      Type: Func<IWebDriver, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>>
      The list of IWebElement once it is located and visible.
  ```
- [VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy Method (ReadOnlyCollection)](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/M_OpenQA_Selenium_Support_UI_ExpectedConditions_ElementToBeClickable_1.htm)

  ```
  public static Func<IWebDriver, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>> VisibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(
      ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements
  )

  Parameters
      elements
            Type: System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>
            list of WebElements

  Return Value
      Type: Func<IWebDriver, ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement>>
      The list of IWebElement once those are located and visible.
  ```